# How to access specific fields in Firestore DB in Next.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

I'm trying to access a specific field in a document with the same name as user.uid. I'm using useAuthState from react-firebase-hooks to get user credentials(uid).
[image: Path to the field]
I can console log all the documents in Users collection using this code:

```
  const getUser = async () => {
    const UsersDB = collection(firestore, "Users");
    
    const userDocs = await getDocs(UsersDB)

    userDocs.forEach(doc => {
      console.log(doc.data())
    })
  };
  
   useEffect(() => {
    getUser()
  }, [])
```

All documents in Users collection have the same name as user uid's. How can I console log the only document with the same name as logged in user uid and how would I call a specific field like isAdmin shown above in the code?

EDIT: I did try this:

```
  const getUser = async () => {
    const UserDBData = collection(firestore, "Users", user.uid);
    
    const docsSnap = await getDocs(UserDBData)

    docsSnap.forEach(doc => {
      console.log(doc.data())
    })
  };
  
   useEffect(() => {
    getUser()
  }, [])
```

But I get this error: Invalid collection reference. Collection references must have an odd number of segments

Comment: If you know the ID of the specific user, why wouldn't you just get that one document instead of getting all of the documents in Users?

Comment: I did but I get an error. I tried this: const UserDBData = collection(firestore, "Users", user.uid); ERROR: Invalid collection reference. Collection references must have an odd number of segments

Answer (score 0):

The error comes from this code:

```
collection(firestore, "Users", user.uid)
```

You're calling the `collection` function, which returns a reference to a collection of document, but then you pass it the path to a specific user's **document**, which is not a collection.

To get the document for just that single user:

```
const UserDBData = doc(firestore, "Users", user.uid);

const docSnap = await getDoc(UserDBData)

console.log(docSnap.data())
```

Also see the Firebase documentation on [getting a single document from Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document), which also shows how to do some additional error handling.

Comment: Thanks!  It does console log the document for the logged in user but once I refresh I get an error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'uid')

Comment: That means the original error message is gone, and you have a new problem. At a glance, it seems that `user` does not have a value - so you'll want to set a breakpoint on the line and see why that is the case. If you can't solve it with that and after searching for the error message (as I'm pretty sure this has come up before), post a new question, with its own [minimal repro](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (which for example likely won't need any code related to Firestore, since the error message is around Firebase Authentication).

Comment: When I console 'user' it shows all Firebase credentials including uid. So idk where to even start with asking a question. It's also weird it displays the correct data in console but after hard refresh I get an error on the same thing. Spent hours just for this one thing which seems very simple but holy.